# Unable to convert date string to NSDate using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

This is my iOS program fragment.I had some debugging, but have no choice.Why the log is returning null for createDate? Is the first time I use stackoverflow, so I don't know how to reply, I'm sorry.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
//    Mon May 18 22:11:56 +0800 2015    _created_at

NSDate *createDate = [fmt dateFromString:_created_at];

NSLog(@"*****%@-----%@-----%@",createDate,[fmt stringFromDate:createDate],_created_at);
//NSLog：*****(null)-----(null)-----Mon May 18 22:50:28 +0800 2015
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: What are you confused about? Why the log is returning null for createDate and [fmt stringFromDate:createDate]?

Comment: Please clarify your question and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Comment: Why the log is returning null for createDate?  Is the first time I use stackoverflow, so I don't know how to reply, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply, this is me the code after the correction. But I don't know how to choose the right answer now, very sorry.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale* local =[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] ;
    [fmt setLocale:local];
    fmt.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";

//    Mon May 18 22:11:56 +0800 2015    _created_at

    NSDate *createDate = [fmt dateFromString:_created_at];

    NSLog(@"*****%@-----%@",createDate,_created_at);
    //NSLog：*****2015-05-18 16:12:21 +0000-----Tue May 19 00:12:21 +0800 2015
```